# App does not save data before activity closes, or not loading data after activity is created - SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

[Data on main activity doesn't save / load properly with SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538632/data-on-main-activity-doesnt-save-load-properly-with-sharedpreferences)

See link above to original questions and responses from other people... to sum it up, SharedPreferences is either not saving or not loading data properly... see pictures of my app, it will better show the problem:

[Screenshots of my app in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff3kD.jpg)

As far as the code behind main activity, I have tried different things suggested by different people, and i appreciate anyone who was or is willing to help :)  At this very moment, this is the code relevant to the problem in MainActivity:  (Please note:  To save on space, I am only showing one Bundle (getFromQuizOne), but I have the same kind of Bundle / Bundle code for all 10 quizzes.    Also, I only put in one quiz button setOnClickListener, but same kind of code applies for all other quiz buttons).

```
            //Get points from Quiz One
            Bundle getFromQuizOne = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(getFromQuizOne != null)
            {
                //Get points from Quiz One
                numberQuizOnePoints = getFromQuizOne.getInt("PointsFromAllQuizOne");

                SharedPreferences shareInt = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(QUIZ, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editInt = shareInt.edit();

                //Save the value of points from Quiz One with SharedPreferences
                editInt.putInt("quizOnePointsYeah", numberQuizOnePoints);
                editInt.commit();

                //Call arrayMethod, which uses for loop to get and display value of points for each quiz
                arrayMethod();
            }//end if

            //My actual project has same kind of Bundle for all other quizzes, but to save space, i am just listing Bundle for quiz 1


            //Directs user to Quiz One, first screen
            quizOneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //Subtract out any points that user already got for Quiz 1 from total...
                    //In case user wants to or has to re-take Quiz 1
                    totalPoints = totalPoints - numberQuizOnePoints;

                    //Subtract out any points that user already got for Quiz 1 from itself, equal 0
                    numberQuizOnePoints -= numberQuizOnePoints;

                    //Go to the Quiz One, first screen

                    Intent directToQuizOnePartOne = new Intent();
                    directToQuizOnePartOne.setClass(getBaseContext(), QuizOnePartOne.class);
                    startActivity(directToQuizOnePartOne);
                    finish();
                }//end void onClick quizOne
            });//end setOnClickListener quizOne

            //My project has button click listeners for all 10 quizzes, that look similar to quizOneButton onClick action listener, but to save on space, I didn't paste it here


        public void arrayMethod()
        {
            int[] points = {numberQuizOnePoints, numberQuizTwoPoints, numberQuizThreePoints,
            numberQuizFourPoints, numberQuizFivePoints, numberQuizSixPoints, numberQuizSevenPoints,
            numberQuizEightPoints, numberQuizNinePoints, numberQuizTenPoints};

            String[] prefKeys = {"quizOnePointsYeah", "quizTwoPointsYeah", "quizThreePointsYeah",
            "quizFourPointsYeah", "quizFivePointsYeah", "quizSixPointsYeah", "quizSevenPointsYeah",
            "quizEightPointsYeah", "quizNinePointsYeah", "quizTenPointsYeah"};

            SharedPreferences shareInt = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(QUIZ, MODE_PRIVATE);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (shareInt.getInt(prefKeys[i], 0) > 0)
                {
                    points[i] = shareInt.getInt(prefKeys[i], 0);
                }//end if
                else
                {
                    points[i] = 0;
                }//end else
            }//end for loop

            //Sum up points from each quiz, and put sum in totalPoints variable
            totalPoints = numberQuizOnePoints + numberQuizTwoPoints + numberQuizThreePoints
                    + numberQuizFourPoints + numberQuizFivePoints + numberQuizSixPoints
                    + numberQuizSevenPoints + numberQuizEightPoints + numberQuizNinePoints
                    + numberQuizTenPoints;


            quizOnePointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizOnePoints));
            quizTwoPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizTwoPoints));
            quizThreePointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizThreePoints));
            quizFourPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizFourPoints));
            quizFivePointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizFivePoints));
            quizSixPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizSixPoints));
            quizSevenPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizSevenPoints));
            quizEightPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizEightPoints));
            quizNinePointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizNinePoints));
            quizTenPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", numberQuizTenPoints));
            actualPointsText.setText(String.format("%d", totalPoints));
        }//end void arrayMethod
    }//end class MainMenu
```

Comment: Please do not post the entire codes in the question. Only relevant codes are sufficient in most of the cases.

Comment: So much repetitive code. Try to put such code in methods, maybe use int arrays for points, etc. etc. We only need code where you are reading and saving the value.

Comment: You need to lookup onSaveInstanceState, and onRestoreInstanceState. On my phone otherwise I would elaborate.

Comment: I wrote an [ORM library](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/RelationalPreferences) for SharedPreference, thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I know what you want, but from my understanding you should be loading and saving that data during a state that you know will get called such as `onPause();`. You should also take a look at the [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

here's a somewhat related snippet from my app

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // the UI component values are saved here.
    outState.putStringArrayList("mList", new ArrayList<>(fretList));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState); // the UI component values are saved here.
    // if there is a non empty bundle, then pull arraylist from it, clear old list
    // just in case, and add all bundle items to it.
    if (inState != null) {
        ArrayList bundledList = inState.getStringArrayList("mList");
        if (bundledList != null && bundledList.size() > 0) {
            fretList.clear();
            fretList.addAll(bundledList);
        }
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state restored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Edit: I'm now looking over your other linked question trying to understand your question better. You can do some simple checking with `Log.d()` to find out where you lose the bundle/data

```
if (getFromQuizOne != null)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "not null");
    } else {
        Log.d("Test", "null");
    }
```

If you want to explicitly save something without waiting you can move it to your own method and call it whenever you want (this is using shared prefs rather than bundle):

```
public void save(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putString("someString", text);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: it sounds as though onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState are used in the event that an Activity is closed do to system restraints (such as turning phone around, changing from portrait to landscape), whereas my MainActivity is closed due to normal app behavior, I am calling the finish(); method in each quiz button... once user clicks a quiz button, main activity closes, quiz # activity opens... and then main activity is created again after quiz # is done and passes points earned... should i still use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState in my case?

Comment: That's what I have linked in my answer, did you look through it and understand it?

Comment: I need to read into it more i think, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: what i'm really wondering is if i should be closing MainActivity at all... I can just leave it running in the background while user is doing the quiz, but then i'm not sure how i would pass points back to MainActivity, i tried that originally, to just not close MainActivity when user starts a quiz, but when it comes time to pass points from Quiz # back to MainActivity, I'm really just creating a second instance of MainActivity, while the original one still exists

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken you could use a static variable like an array to hold those values and it might work if the original activity doesn't get destroyed (which you can't really control in Android).